# Getting an event.preventDefault(); is not a function. Why is it not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with react and following a handful of tutorials for Form submission where I run into this problem in my console:

```
contact.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function(…)
```

Here is my code:

contact.js

```
class ContactForm extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('hello');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleTouchTap = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  }

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Paper className="Form" zDepth={2}>
          <Formsy.Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <FormsyText
              name="Enter Name"
              floatingLabelText="Enter your name"
            />
            <FormsyText
              name="Enter email address"
              floatingLabelText="Enter your email address"
            />
            <FormsyText
              name="message"
              floatingLabelText="What can I do for you?"
            />
            <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
               type="submit"
               label="Submit your message"
               primary={true}
            />
            <Snackbar
              open={this.state.open}
              message="Thank your for submitting your message. I'll get back to you as soon as I can!"
              autoHideDuration={2000}
              onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
            />
          </Formsy.Form>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { ContactForm };
```

As you can see in my code and from what I can tell, I've properly bound `handleSubmit` to my `ContactForm` and should be calling it correctly on the `onSubmit` handler with `this.handleSubmit`. What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are not using a default form...

It's Formsy

From the docs

https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md#onsubmit

> onSubmit(data, resetForm, invalidateForm)
>
> Takes a
>   function to run when the submit button has been clicked.
>
> The first argument is the data of the form. The second argument will
>   reset the form. The third argument will invalidate the form by taking
>   an object that maps to inputs. This is useful for server side
>   validation. E.g. {email: "This email is taken"}. Resetting or
>   invalidating the form will cause setState to run on the form element
>   component.

Answer (score 1):

Formsy passes the form data as first parameter into the submit event handler. **This form data does not have a function `preventDefault()`.**

If you refer to the internal implementation of the submit mechanism, you will see that `preventDefault()` is always called by default:

```
submit: function (event) {

  event && event.preventDefault();

  // Trigger form as not pristine.
  // If any inputs have not been touched yet this will make them dirty
  // so validation becomes visible (if based on isPristine)
  this.setFormPristine(false);
  var model = this.getModel();
  this.props.onSubmit(model, this.resetModel, this.updateInputsWithError);
  this.state.isValid ? this.props.onValidSubmit(model, this.resetModel, this.updateInputsWithError) : this.props.onInvalidSubmit(model, this.resetModel, this.updateInputsWithError);

},
```

[Source](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/15493dce67433746391f4eb42c7f994b72cf5df9/src/main.js#L103)